# How do I read the dimensions to create a PCB footprint?

Tags: pcb-design, datasheet, footprint, drawing

I'm trying to make a PCB footprint for the [SSD1306](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/SSD1306.pdf) ribbon strip, and am unsure of the correct dimensions for the solder pads. The horizontal dimensions are clear enough but I don't know where the pads start and finish vertically speaking.

And also what does the "LS" refer to in the red circle?

[image]

Guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're referring to the 31 pins, each pin has a width of .4mm and is 21mm wide from the middle of each end pin. LS stands for lead space but I'm not sure if it applies to these pins. by creating 31 pads and spacing them to the 21mm, it should match the cable pins.

Comment: I understood the horizontal dimensions as they're quite clear, but the vertical sizing is a bit ambiguous (at least to me). Lead space makes sense, I think that is where I had taken the pads to be contained within but wanted to double check